# pagerslidingtabstrip tabs not showing in lollipop version

Tags: android

I am using pagerslidingtabstrip in my android application. It is working in all versions except lopllipop verions. In lollipop versions tabbar is not showing anything. Please help me out

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

</com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1* add your color with name tabBackgroundColor

2* In class PagerSlidingTabStrip replace with this code

*In method updateTabStyles

v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.tabBackgroundColor);

hope..its help u